# Handle correcly state with pegtl grammar

Tags: c++, peg

I'm very new to peg and pegtl, so probably I'm missing something.
I have a grammar very similar to the following one:

```
using namespace tao::pegtl;

struct A : one<'A'> { };
struct B : one<'B'> { };

struct comp : seq<plus<sor<seq<A, B>, A>>,eof> { };

template< typename Rule >
struct test_action : nothing< Rule > {};

template<>
struct test_action<A>
{
    template< typename Input >
    static void apply(const Input& in)
    {
        std::cout << "A";
    }
};

template<>
struct test_action<B>
{
    template< typename Input >
    static void apply(const Input& in)
    {
        std::cout << "B";
    }
};

void test()
{
    parse< comp, test_action >(memory_input("AAB", ""));
}
```

The parse works great, but there is too many activation of test_action::apply.
The program outputs "AAAB", because, if I understand well, the parse tries the first alternative (AB) for the first character and fails, then proceeds 
with the other (A). But even if it "rewinds", it always call test_action::apply.
What is the correct way to handle this situation?
My intent is to output "AAB", possibly without complicate the grammar.

Comment: Maybe add [tag:peg]? I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked to pegtl library authors and they kindly give me the correct way: the best thing to do is make your parser construct a parse tree, which is easy to fix when it backtracks using simple push and pop operations.

I developed the code below for who had similar doubts.

- avoid backtracking in rules with attached actions:

  ```
  using namespace tao::pegtl;

  struct A : one<'A'> { };
  struct B : one<'B'> { };

  struct real_A : A {};
  struct real_AB : seq<A, B> {};

  struct comp : seq<plus<sor<real_AB, real_A>>,eof> { };

  template< typename Rule >
  struct test_action : nothing< Rule > {};

  template<>
  struct test_action<real_A>
  {
      template< typename Input >
      static void apply(const Input& in)
      {
          std::cout << "A";
      }
  };

  template<>
  struct test_action<real_AB>
  {
      template< typename Input >
      static void apply(const Input& in)
      {
          std::cout << "AB";
      }
  };



  void test()
  {
      parse< comp, test_action >(memory_input("AAB", ""));
  }
  ```
- build a parse tree:

  ```
  using namespace tao::pegtl;

  struct A : one<'A'> { };
  struct B : one<'B'> { };


  struct comp : seq<plus<sor<seq<A, B>, A>>, eof> { };

  template< typename Rule >
  struct test_action : nothing< Rule > {};


  void test()
  {
      auto root = parse_tree::parse<comp>(memory_input("AAB", ""));
  }
  ```

Comment: as you have answered the question yourself, you might want to mark it as "answered" accordingly